# Is it possible to have the D-Link DIR-628 run in wireless bridge mode?

Tags: wifi, d-link

Short of installing 3rd party software, does the D-Link DIR-628 run in bridged wireless?
I'm trying to have the dlink hook up to an existing linksys wireless router to add more range/get stronger signal.

Answer (score 2):

From my research it appears that the DIR-628 does not seam to support WDS, and isn't even supported by tomato or dd-wrt.  Unfortunately you may be out of luck.